# Can't reference UWP 10.0.16299 from a netcoreapp2.0 project?

Tags: uwp, .net-core

I have two projects in VS 2017.  One project is a .netcoreapp 2.0 which contains my test cases.  The other one is a UWP 10.0.16299 (minimum) App project, which contains the classes I would like to test.  I am able to run the test app without referencing UWP, but when I do, I get a the following message:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error NU1201  Project App is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0
>   (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Project App supports: uap10.0.16299
>   (UAP,Version=v10.0.16299) UnitTestProject3 C:\UnitTestProject3\UnitTestProject3.csproj    1

According to dotnetcore info, here's what the test project is running:

> .NET Command Line Tools (2.1.4)
>
> Product Information:  Version:            2.1.4  Commit SHA-1 hash: 
>   5e8add2190
>
> Runtime Environment:  OS Name:     Windows  OS Version:  10.0.16299 
>   OS Platform: Windows  RID:         win10-x64  Base Path:   C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\
>
> Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host
>
> Version  : 2.0.5   Build    :
>   17373eb129b3b05aa18ece963f8795d65ef8ea54

From what I've read, I should be able to reference the app from my project, but I am also confused. It appears it can't be done, but then I get suggestion that it can be done. I looked at the matrix and it makes no sense because of the ever changing terminology.

What can be wrong?  The reason I am using a .netcoreapp is because I couldn't get the UWP version of MSTest to work or xUnit.

Comment: "From what I've read, I should be able to reference the app from my project". You probably misunderstood what you read. Face the facts, and that's the reality. If your real question is how to run UWP unit testing, you have to heavily modify this question to reflect that.

Comment: Wow!  You are really mean!  Are you sure your not Lex Luther?  If it will not work, fine.  That's all I needed to know.  I didn't want a punch in the gut.  Do you realize how broken this batch of code from MS is?  I took a 3 year long sabbatical from programming and I'm just getting reacquainted.  .NET was once a stable, highly productive and fun!  Now, it's a big dysfunctional mess!

Comment: Is it your habit to say something is "broken" or somebody is "mean"? Microsoft designed .NET Core and UWP to be incompatible to each other, which should have been well known if you do read the proper materials. Personally I blogged about such a long time ago, https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff That's why I said you misunderstood the concept. BTW, .NET Core is "stable, highly productive and fun" to me, so leave it alone if you don't plan to learn something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UWP apps can only reference the .NET standard class library template, not .NET Core class library template. You can have a look at this [blog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt694084.aspx)

Where you can see this:"Depending on how you target your projects, it’s possible to have .NET Core code run on the .NET Framework, Mono and Xamarin platforms, on Windows 8 and Windows Phone, and on the Universal Windows Platform (UWP). To learn more, check out the [.NET Platform Standard](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md)"

And if you have any problem related to unit test for UWP app, please modify your tags and your question or post a new question(as mentioned by Lex).